# Powershell execution policy remotesigned contradiction?

Tags: powershell, security, executionpolicy

please look at the following URL: [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6#remotesigned)

Now it says the following about downloaded scripts:

"Runs scripts that are downloaded from the Internet and not signed, if the scripts are unblocked, such as by using the Unblock-File cmdlet."

I just downloaded a script from the technet gallery (PS2EXE) and I could run the test script that was included just fine without using the Unblock_file cmdlet. What is going on? Am i misunderstanding what  Microsoft is telling me or is this a glitch?

Comment: How exactly you download it? "Downloaded from internet" flag is preserved in alternative data stream. It is responsibility of downloader program (browser) to set it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`help unblock-file`:

> Internally, the Unblock-File cmdlet removes the Zone.Identifier alternate data stream, which has a value of "3" to indicate that it was downloaded from the Internet.

The idea of a file being "remote" or "coming from the internet" is data on your local computer filesystem which has to be put there by the tool that downloads the file, it's not included in the file during the download.

If you downloaded a file through Internet Explorer, maybe FireFox, Invoke-WebRequest, these will add it. If you download with something else, the tool might not add this alternate stream.

See how it behaves:

```
# Show folder is empty
PS C:\temp\> Get-ChildItem


# Make a test script which prints Hello World, and run it
PS C:\temp\> "'Hello World'" | Set-Content -Path .\test.ps1
PS C:\temp\> .\test.ps1
Hello World


# Show the file exists
PS C:\temp\> Get-ChildItem

    Directory: C:\temp\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       01/08/2018     22:07             15 test.ps1


# Add the Zone Identifier alternate data stream
PS C:\temp\> "[ZoneTransfer]`nZoneId=3" | Set-Content -Path 'test.ps1' -Stream 'Zone.Identifier'


# Show that it doesn't appear in a normal directory listing:
PS C:\temp\> Get-ChildItem

    Directory: C:\temp\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       01/08/2018     22:08             15 test.ps1



# Show how it blocks the file from running
PS C:\temp\> .\test.ps1
.\test.ps1 : File C:\temp\test.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\temp\test.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot
run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see
about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\test.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess


# Show file content
PS C:\temp\> Get-Content -Path .\test.ps1
'Hello World'


# Show alternate data stream content
PS C:\temp\> Get-Content -Path .\test.ps1 -Stream 'Zone.Identifier'
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3


# Unblock-File removes this alternate stream
PS C:\temp\> Unblock-File .\test.ps1


# Script runs again
PS C:\temp\> .\test.ps1
Hello World
```

So the main question is, if you run `Get-Content file.ps1:Zone.Identifier` and see the ZoneId is `3` *and* can still run the script, *and* `Get-ExecutionPolicy` is RemoteSigned, then you have something odd going on.

But my guess is the download tool did not add this data, so the file looks just like a locally created one.

NB. RemoteSigned is not intended to be a security feature, it's intended to be a "help guard against accidentally running scripts before reading them and deliberately choosing to run them" check, like an "are you sure?" box, not like a password prompt.

Comment: I will clarify: I downloaded the file while it was in a ZIP file. So this explains why this ZoneId flag was not set. I will admit though that could have done the help unblock-file myself so I agree with the down vote. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I just  downloaded another script while it was NOT in a zip file, just plain .PS1 with Chrome. I could run it just fine, while executionPolicy was set on remoteSigned. This file dit not have this zone identifier attribute set to 3.. It kind of makes me wonder how much of a help guard this actually is. I understand now that it is not a security feature, but it sure does look like one when you first read into it. btw: i also tried your snippet of code and the results were kind of strange: when I went from zone.identifier 3 to unblocked, i had to restart my PS session for it to have effect.

Comment: @AngryRoss oh, so Chrome doesn't do it? It's not just "from the internet" - if you go into IE, then Tools -> Options, and the Security tab, see at the top there are "select a zone to view or change security settings" choices - those are the zones. The file has to come from a website in the untrusted "Internet" zone, not a local intranet or trusted site, I don't know how non-IE browsers interpret that. Or even for sure if non-IE browsers will do it. What PS version are you on? `$PSVersionTable` will tell you, the top number - 5.1 is current, 4 is reasonable, 3 and 2 are ancient these days.

Comment: i'm using version 5.1.  So in order to have this "help guard" being effective you should have your sysadmins (because only they should have access to PS) only use IE with those settings.... i'm not sure that would be the case for every IT department. IE is also considered ancient by a lot of people (even if that is rightfully so or not). i'm sure a lot of people don't even know about this.. i'm told "set execution policy to remote signed! its secure!11"... but its not. not _really_. Not trying to be snide though, your help and input is much appreciated.

Comment: @AngryRoss "*i'm told "set execution policy to remote signed! its secure!11"... but its not. not really.*" - well considering you can do `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass .\test.ps1` and just walk completely around it, `AllSigned` is not "secure" either. `RemoteSigned` is not secure but .. it's not /less/ secure either. It doesn't change the security one bit, you don't need admin rights to turn it off. If you chose to use "AllSigned" to help you work with lots of PowerShells scripts without accidentally running one you didn't trust, it might help you. Otherwise, it seems annoying.